# Authenticate Community Users in External Rest API

Tags: community, api, single-sign-on, authentication, saml

I have a Community that consumes an external Rest API that requires authentication.

For testing purpose, I hardcoded a username and a password in my apex rest callouts in order to be able to consume my API. It's works fine.

What I need to do now is to implements some sort of SSO between my community and my API, so that once a user authenticates in my community, a SAML is generated and sent to my API that validates the user and sends back a token.
I can later use this token to consume the API.

**How can i achieve this use case please ?** : 
[image]

1. **User login to community**
2. **Community sends SAML assertion to API**
3. **API Checks user info in SAML and authenticates him**
4. **API sends back a JWT Token in order to be consumed**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. What is your question about this proposal/architecture? Please [edit] to ask an explicit question the community can help you with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i edited my question.

Comment: Can the rest api directly validate username and password? If yes you can look at delegated authentication instead of SSO